# How to give Windows 7 access to a file?

Tags: files, encryption, chmod

I have my Ubuntu installation mounted on a 3TB drive and also use it as a storage for large files I use on my Windows 7 Dual boot. Recently I spent a long time encrypting a file for use in Windows. By the end it was 18.6GBS worth of information and encrypting. I would usually move it by a USB drive but my largest one is 16GBs and I cannot compress the file without losing encryptions. So, I mounted my /home folder (the 3TB drive) for use in Windows. The problem is, since I used a command to encrypt the file, it's owner is 'David,' my Ubuntu user. Using

```
sudo chmod 777
```

Just is giving access to other Ubuntu users, not the Windows installation. Please help.

Comment: suco chown 777 give full access on the host, sort of depnds on how you are acessing it from elsewhere, samba ? NFS? ssh ? ftp ? you have to config the server.

Comment: `sudo chown 777` doesn't work because it's `sudo chmod 777`

Comment: Please define `Ubuntu user`

Comment: Where is the file, and what users do you want to access it and how?

Comment: The file is a python compressed file that cannot be moved by USB, and it is in the Ubuntu installation on the same disk, on a separate partition. /dev/sda1 is Ubuntu and /dev/sda2 is Windows Doing `sudo chmod 777` Just gives permissions to all Ubuntu users and not to Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `chmod`, the outside operating system can access the file, given it has right permissions.

Use

```
sudo chmod 777 file
```

Or

```
sudo chmod a+rwx file
```

Comment: a+x does not give full access, `a+rwx`

Comment: Thank  you. FWIW, I did not down vote your answer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen no big deals mate, i just hope op gets his problem solved :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Still says that the Owner of the file is Ubuntu... Also sorry for the extremely delayed response

Comment: @H.Freeze This question is out-dated and no longer relevant. I would like to delete it, but for that to happen I'd need your answer deleted.Think you could do that for me?